# How to run this script against another domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the script below to give me the distinguished name for groups in a spreadsheet I have. The issue is, the groups are located in another domain. How do I point my script to that domain? Issue is I know I have to be logged in to that domain to run it but I cant.

```
$Groups = Get-Content -Path C:\Scripts\DistinguishedName.csv
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group | Select-Object distinguishedName
}
```

Comment: according to the docs for that cmdlet, there is a `-Server` parameter. that is usually used to avoid waiting for replication delays, but i presume ti can be used to access a server on another domain. you will likely need to provide the `-Credential` parameter, too. [*grin*]

Comment: Yes I heard about that but I am having a hard time finding where to insert that CMDLET into my script; any help would be welcomed.

Comment: i don't understand your comment ... the parameter would go where you have your current call >>> `Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Server $OtherDomainServer` <<<

Answer (score 0):

The cmdlets in the Active Directory module support passing in the value of the domain controller you are wanting to query. By default when you call `Get-ADGroup` (or any of the other) it will validate what domain it should query by checking the domain of your current machine.

The other option is to provide the `-Server` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroup)) with the value of the Active Directory Domain Services you want to execute your query against.

You can also provide the `-Credential` parameter with a PSCredential object that contains your login for that other domain. This is required if the current login of your PowerShell session is not authorized to authenticate against that other domain.

So your example script would look something like this:

```
$AdDomain = "whatever.company.local"
$adCred = Get-Credential

$Groups = Get-Content -Path C:\Scripts\DistinguishedName.csv
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Server $AdDomain -Credential $adCred | Select-Object distinguishedName
}
```